# TAB-key doesn't work after running macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet on which most cells are locked but a piece of the worksheet-cells is unlocked.
I have a macro which does the following :

- unlock the workbook
- unlock the sheet
- copy that single sheet in another workbook
- save the new workbook somewhere and close it

Afterwards, the tab-key doesn't work anymore.
It looks like the worksheets loosed the focus, but as soon as I start typing, the content comes in the cell.

When I select another workbook or another sheet in the original workbook, the tab-key is working again.
(When I select another program and return to Excel, that is not enough to get it working again).

I already select and activate the original worksheet at the end of the macro, but that doesn't help.

```
activeworkbook.worksheets("rapport").activate
activeworkbook.worksheets("rapport").select
```

edit : I tried to isolate the problem, and it seems that it has nothing to do with the protection of the workbook or the worksheet.  In a new thread, I give a description of the problem in a small workbook with a small macro.

Comment: *"I have a macro"*: Please [edit] your question and add the macro there.

Comment: How about after activating a **cell** in the worksheet with a such code? `Range("A1").Select`

Comment: Did you use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?