# Tab-key doesn't work with sheet that contains a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a button.
When the button is pressed, code in the worksheet is executed.
The code is very simple

```
Private sub cmdWerf_Click()
    MsgBox "button pressed"
End Sub
```

I have a macro in a module that tries to save a copy of the sheet in a fixed location.

```
Public Sub Isolate_Problem()
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:="d:\efkes\test.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

When running the macro, Excel opens a new workbook, copies the sheet into it, saves it and returns to the original sheet.

But the tab-key doesn't work any longer.

I have to go to another sheet (Alt-F6) and return to the original sheet.  Then it seems the sheet gets the focus again and the tab-key works again.  (Clicking in the original sheet moves the activecell, but the tab-key doesn't work)

The macro works fine if I remove the button on the sheet.

What is going on here.  How can I get the tab-key working again after the macro is executed.

I already posed this question before ([TAB-key doesn't work after running macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391225/tab-key-doesnt-work-after-running-macro)), but the problem wasn't well isolated.  In this thread, I isolated the problem in a small macro.

Kind regards,
Joris Adriaenssens.

Comment: Try to set focus in the sheet you want: Me.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TAB-key doesn't work after running macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391225/tab-key-doesnt-work-after-running-macro).  Could you edit this extra information into your original question please.

Comment: I think the code you posted is not complete. You write in the text "Excel opens a new workbook, copies the sheet into it" but I don't see it in the code.